# What exactly is NSBundle useful for - only to access resources of the .app package?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsbundle

...or could I also get an NSBundle that represents the Documents directory, to easily access contents in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think on iOS it's really only useful for things in the .app package.  It originates in OS X where you can load other bundles as plugins, in which case you use NSBundle instances to access resources from the plugin.